# R need to replace text between slashes in URL

Tags: r, web, web-scraping

I'm trying to replace a number in a URL to improve image quality and can't figure out how to properly escape the / to get it to work.

I need to change://contentinfo.autozone.com/znetcs/product-info/en/US/nip/3289/image/1/
to://contentinfo.autozone.com/znetcs/product-info/en/US/nip/3289/image/10/

of course, https is ahead of both of those URLs, but the forum converts that to an image if I include it.

Comment: `sub("\\d+/?$", "10/", myurl)`

Comment: Thanks!  That  worked :D

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code below on [an online snippet](https://rdrr.io/snippets/) and it worked well. Used the hint of [Aurèle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6197649/aur%C3%A8le) too. Maybe it will give you a hint:

```
url <- "//contentinfo.autozone.com/znetcs/product-info/en/US/nip/3289/image/1/"
    
cat("Simple way\n")
simple <- gsub("/1/","/10/",url)
cat("Before: ", url, "\n")
cat("After: ", simple, "\n")
    
cat("Regex \n") As sugested by Aurèle
regex <- sub("\\d+/?$", "10/", url) 
cat("Before: ", url, "\n")
cat("After: ", regex, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution by Aurèle:

```
sub("\d+/?$", "10/", myurl)
```